# Ways of {coping/dealing} with stress {at work paramedic/in paramedic's work} - which title is correct?

Tags: word-choice, formal-language

I'm writing a thesis in English and I need you to check if these titles are correct. Which one is better in your opinion? It must be formal of course.
Could you check if these title is correct?

> "Ways of dealing with stress at work paramedic."
>
> "Ways of coping with stress at work paramedic."
>
> "Ways of coping with stress in paramedic's work."

If there's a mistake, could you correct it please? Is the article "the" needed before "ways?

Comment: You could also make **paramedic** an adjective (which precedes the noun) and eliminate "ways of" for brevity: "Coping with the stress of paramedic work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few thoughts:

1) In formal contexts like a thesis, I would use "Methods" instead of "Ways."

2) In normal English sentences, you would need to say "The ways," but in a title it's more formal and common to not use "the."

2) The first two sentences are incorrect. You want one noun to represent the work of a paramedic, and "work paramedic" is just two nouns stuck together without an appropriate connection. "Paramedic's work" is not incorrect, but maybe slightly awkward. I would suggest "at work as a paramedic."

3) "Coping" and "dealing" are both appropriate word choices, I personally would lean towards "coping" here.

All together: "Methods of coping with stress at work as a paramedic."

Other options:

"Methods of coping with stress during paramedic work" 
(Although this implies that the coping only happens while working and not at home, etc.)

"Methods of coping with stress for paramedics" (This would be the appropriate title if your thesis makes *suggestions*, rather than just describing what paramedics do to cope with stress.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What about this sentence?:

"Methods of coping with stress in the work of a paramedic”

Is it correct? Can I use it?

Comment: It's correct, but sounds a little strange. I'd recommend what TRomano above suggested and use paramedic as an adjective: "Methods of coping with the stress of paramedic work"

Comment: But is it still ok if I use your version: "Methods of coping with stress at work as a paramedic". ? It sounds more specific to me because I'm focusing on "one person", let's say. The version: "Methods of coping with the stress of paramedic work" sounds to general to me. But I'm a Polish speaker so I'm not 100% sure. So one more time, could I use "Methods of coping with stress at work as a paramedic." without any problem?

Comment: Yes, it's alright. You're right that "Methods of coping with the stress of paramedic work" does sound more general.